# Adding a contact in chat application using XMPP.

Tags: xmpp, chat

How can I add a contact in my chat app using XMPP using open fire as server?

Comment: You should add more information

Comment: Can you give some more info as to what you have at the moment? At the moment this question is so open-ended, it is hard to provide an answer that might work for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Smack api](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/).

```
Connection conn = new Connection();
conn.getRoster();
```

Comment: Hi Rahul , Thanks for answering. I want to make a friend list in my chat application .
for this i asked question how add a friend in my chat app . plz tell me..

Comment: getRoster retrieves the contact list only list. But he wants to add a new contact to the list.

Comment: @nitintyagi Just let me know if you have any queries regarding chat application using xmpp/openfire.
Thanks